# in css/js: make links on mouse over (hover) shows what is in h1

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink

I have a css file that I want to add to an option for links, to make them grab and show the first h1 tag from the linked page, and display it when the mouse is hovered over the link (as a title, or alt text). (or how to do it with a central javascript file?

Example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
any link in that page, shows the title of the linked page.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something to your question, you're just talking about the regular HTML Title attribute. At least, on your example page, that's all that is happening - the links have titles.

Comment: no the links do not have titles, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorisiformes  if you edit and see it is just linked to a page, and the displayed text on hover is not in the code.

Comment: That's because MediaWiki markup isn't the same as HTML. The markup automatically inserts the `title` attribute based on the linked page. But that has nothing to do with HTML or CSS at all. It's processing done on the Wikipedia servers.